# abstract class property from Factory C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-core, polymorphism, abstract-class

Consider the following abstract class :

```
public abstract class BuildingBase
{
    public abstract BuildingType Type { get; }

}
```

this class is inherited by two classes :

```
public class Appartment : BuildingBase
{
    public override BuildingType Type => BuildingType.Appartment;
}

public class House: BuildingBase
{
    public override BuildingType Type => BuildingType.House;
}
```

I have a factory that should 'build' based on the type passed :

```
public class Builder {
    public BuildingBase Build(BuildingType type) {
        // how to get this implemented without if / else .. case when ... etc 
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe with `Dictionary<BuildingType, Func<BuildingBase>>` ...

Comment: As an aside, note that if you intend to use  a "service locator" factory class like that outside of a composition root, [some consider it an anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) - although not everyone does.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use generics in this case, like this:

```
public class Builder
{
    public TBuildingBase Build<TBuildingType>()
        where TBuildingBase : BuildingBase, new()
    {
        var result = new TBuildingBase();
        ...
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if you require the `Enum` as an input. I'm afraid that if you do want to stick with it, your choices are either an if-else construct, a constructor map like @Selvin mentioned, or using reflection (ugh).